# Radio loud AGN restarting as Radio Quiet AGN?

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, radio-astronomy, active-galaxy

Is it possible for a Radio-loud object (eg., an FRI galaxy) to evolve into a Radio-quiet (eg., a Seyfert) source?

Also, can this happen via AGN restart? That is, have there been instances where the active nuclei in a Radio-loud object switches off, and then restarts as a weaker Radio-quiet source?

Comment: I know a paper by Barišić et al. that concludes that massive, quiescent galaxies at z~1 will switch on a jet mode AGN (radio-loud) about once every Gyr, but not sure if they switch back to radio quiet or quasar mode: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aa8768/meta

Comment: Possible 2017 paper of interest: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aa745d/pdf